# Unmet Dependencies for handbrake-gtk

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, handbrake

I have reviewed the suggestions at [[How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)]. As yet, my issue remains. Here's hoping the good folk here can help me.

```
   sudo apt-get install handbrake-gtk                              
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 handbrake-gtk : Depends: gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.




   cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release i386 (20121017.2)]/ quantal main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted multiverse
deb-src http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted multiverse

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted multiverse
deb-src http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring universe
deb-src http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring universe
deb http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates universe
deb-src http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security main restricted multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security main restricted multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security universe

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ raring partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ raring partner


## Custom software
# deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org raring main # disabled on upgrade to raring
deb http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/op/stable/debian/ lsb3.2 main




   cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/banshee-team/ppa/ubuntu quantal main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu raring main # disabled on upgrade to raring
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu raring main # disabled on upgrade to raring
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu quantal main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu quantal main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu raring main # disabled on upgrade to raring
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu raring main # disabled on upgrade to raring
# deb http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu precise main # disabled on upgrade to raring
deb http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu precise main
# deb http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu precise main # disabled on upgrade to raring
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/flacon/ppa/ubuntu raring main # disabled on upgrade to raring
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/flacon/ppa/ubuntu raring main # disabled on upgrade to raring
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/flacon/ppa/ubuntu quantal main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/flacon/ppa/ubuntu quantal main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/flacon/ppa/ubuntu raring main # disabled on upgrade to raring
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/flacon/ppa/ubuntu raring main # disabled on upgrade to raring
# deb http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu ./ # disabled on upgrade to raring
deb http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu ./
# deb http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu ./ # disabled on upgrade to raring
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kilian/f.lux/ubuntu raring main # disabled on upgrade to raring
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/kilian/f.lux/ubuntu raring main # disabled on upgrade to raring
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kilian/f.lux/ubuntu quantal main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/kilian/f.lux/ubuntu quantal main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kilian/f.lux/ubuntu raring main # disabled on upgrade to raring
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/kilian/f.lux/ubuntu raring main # disabled on upgrade to raring
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu raring main # disabled on upgrade to raring
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu quantal main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu quantal main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu raring main # disabled on upgrade to raring
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/rye/ubuntuone-extras/ubuntu raring main # disabled on upgrade to raring
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/rye/ubuntuone-extras/ubuntu raring main # disabled on upgrade to raring
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/rye/ubuntuone-extras/ubuntu quantal main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/rye/ubuntuone-extras/ubuntu quantal main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/rye/ubuntuone-extras/ubuntu raring main # disabled on upgrade to raring
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/rye/ubuntuone-extras/ubuntu raring main # disabled on upgrade to raring
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/skype-wrapper/ppa/ubuntu quantal main
# deb http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam # disabled on upgrade to raring
# deb-src http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam # disabled on upgrade to raring
deb http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam
deb-src http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam
# deb http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam # disabled on upgrade to raring
# deb-src http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam # disabled on upgrade to raring
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu raring main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu raring main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu raring main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu raring main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu raring main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu raring main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu raring main # disabled on upgrade to raring
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu raring main # disabled on upgrade to raring
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu quantal main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu quantal main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu raring main # disabled on upgrade to raring
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu raring main # disabled on upgrade to raring
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/puddletag/ubuntu raring main # disabled on upgrade to raring
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/puddletag/ubuntu raring main # disabled on upgrade to raring
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/puddletag/ubuntu quantal main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/puddletag/ubuntu quantal main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/puddletag/ubuntu raring main # disabled on upgrade to raring
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/puddletag/ubuntu raring main # disabled on upgrade to raring
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu raring main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu raring main
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To install the latest Handbrake in Ubuntu 12.10, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-releases
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install handbrake-gtk
```

Or just click on [**Install Handbrake** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/handbrake-gtk/)

<sup>Source:Handbrake</sup>